# SQLAlchemy 'no such table' when trying to reference session from imported module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an app I am using where all of my models and my session are stored within a single models.py file:

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String, DateTime, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property, hybrid_method


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///bidbot.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class AgentLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'agentlog'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime,default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    ingroups = Column(String)
    total_calls = Column(Integer)
    calls_waiting = Column(Integer)
    agents_logged_in = Column(Integer)
    agents_in_calls = Column(Integer)
    agents_waiting = Column(Integer)
    agents_paused = Column(Integer)
    agents_in_dispo = Column(Integer)
    agents_in_dial = Column(Integer)

    def create_new():
        session.add(AgentLog())
        session.commit()
```

As you can see, I have a custom create_new method which uses the session to create a new object.

If I run this models.py file on its own:

```
python -i models.py
```

Then I can call the AgentLog.create_new() function and it creates a new record.

However, I am importing models.py into my higher level package:

```
from models.py import *
```

And when I run the same function on the model:

```
AgentLog.create_new()
```

I now get a no such table exists error... Which is confusing because I believe the method should have access to the exact same session object.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: agentlog
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! When I imported the package, it was defining the engine with the relative path based on the importing directory, not the models.py module.

I needed to update the path to use relative directory based on the models.py file:

```
import os

DATABASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\bidbot.db'
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+DATABASE_DIR, echo=True)
```